# Adding a Win32 menu bar to pre-existing GUI

Tags: c++, winapi, menubar

Menus are pretty popular in many applications:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz5Fn.gif)

I've read a lot of threads and have learned out how to add a menu bar to your gui:

```
//Pseudocode

//..RegisterClassEx

HMENU Menu = CreateMenu();
HMENU Tools = CreateMenu();

AppendMenu(Menu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)Tools, L"Tools");
AppendMenu(Tools, MF_STRING, 1, L"Test");
SetMenu(hwnd_to_gui, Menu);

//...
//..GetMessage
//..TranslateMessage
//..DispatchMessage
```

First you RegisterClassEx on your WNDCLASSEX struct that has a property called "lpfnWndProc" which directs to the function to be called when DispatchMessage is called. Then you actually create the menu bar. Finally, you set up a loop that calls GetMessage, and if a message is received, it will translate and dispatch it, effectively calling the lpfnWndProc function.

I was wondering if you could do this with an already existing gui. For example, the console application. I know I can easily set up the menu bar, but handling the input seems to be hard for me.

[Console Application w/ Menu Bar Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0xos.png)

I have a loop that calls GetMessage, however it seems to be picking up no input.
More information:

- I am overwriting the current WNDCLASSEX (RegisterClassEx) with a copy of the old one (achieved from GetClassInfoEx) with the only modification that is the "lpfnWndProc" function (to handle input differently).
- The rewrite seems to be successful, I am just not picking up any input from the GetMessage function (I am clicking buttons, etc.)

Any help on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Just to be clear: You are trying to take an existing executable and modify it by adding a menu to it.

Comment: @MikelF Oh no, I meant an existing GUI. For example, say I had one module (DLL) that would create a gui, then another one (DLL) that would add in a menu bar. Basically DLL #2 would attach a menu bar onto the gui created in DLL #1. It's like adding a menu bar onto the regular old console application. (Not actually tampering with an executable!)

Comment: It's not like adding a menu bar to a console window. In the console car, you are adding a menu bar to another application without it's permission. In the two DLL case, they are both in the same process and can coordinate their actions.

Comment: You cannot add a menu bar to the Console window. It is not designed for this.

Comment: Basically you can make either a console application or a windowed one. Haven't ever seen a hybrid of the two. Can you post us a pic? It would look and feel really weird. And... GUI stands for "Graphical User Interface", something a console application is definitely NOT! And finally it's not just the UI, the logic and implementation is radically different as well, as windowed applications are supposed to be "user-initiated, event-driven", so your console application would need to be modified, to conform to this specification.